# How to compare the images not only with histogram?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, compare

I'm programming about comparing with two images.
Thanks to stackoverflow and google, I could get information about comparing ways.

Most of them are the ways with comparing histogram included in OpenCV.
They are cool usually.

However, in some cases, the problem happens.

Let me give some examples.

[image] [image]

Two images are the same except the color. (actually, it is inversed.) In this case, the outlines of images are the same, but with histogram comparing, it says there's no concern between the two images.

From that time, I wondered whether there is an algorithm or method which compares not only histogram but also outlines. I also think 'outline' is very ambiguous, but I don't know how I explain with other words.

Thanks for reading. :)

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-input-psnr-ssim/video-input-psnr-ssim.html

Comment: Are you talking about measuring the similarity between two images？ If so, that's a tough question.

Comment: if you always expect contours you should extract contours and match shapes.

Comment: You could do a Canny Edge Detection on both images and then compare the results.

Comment: Thanks for all comments!
Yang Kui // Yes, measuring is my final object.
Mark Setchell // I'll read again Canny Edge Detection part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not one method which can be applied to all the situation. Whatever image comparison method you want to choose, you must think about your requirement and the possible image set first.

If you don't know anything about the two images which you want to compare then, you must use a combination of different techniques like histogram matching, template matching, feature matching and several other.

For this particular case where the colors are different but the structure is same, you can use the following strategy:

1. Find the contours in each image.
2. You will get two contour images....one for each image
3. apply template matching on it.

Comment: Thanks for helping! I haven't heard about those methods.
I'll search about those!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Hu moments](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#humoments).

```
// Find contours
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(image, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
cv::Moments mom = cv::moments(contours[0]); 
double hu[7];
cv::HuMoments(mom, hu); // now in hu are your 7 Hu-Moments
```

The hu moments are a vector of 7 components. If you extract the vectors for both images then you can compare them using a quadratic difference. It will look like this:

```
float Distance::distEuclidean(const std::vector<float>& query, const std::vector<float>& item_db)
{
float sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < query.size();i++)
{
    float v1 = query.at(i);
    float v2 = item_db.at(i);
    sum += (v1-v2)*(v1-v2);
}
float distance = sqrt(sum);
return distance;
}
```

Please note that hu[7] is a c vector and the input of the function is a c++ std::vector

Comment: Thanks for kind examples! I'll try to adapt that way. I'm very sorry that I can't check both of answers.
I just wonder whether it is completed in a few (milli)seconds.

Comment: @TwilighT: you can upvote it, if it is helpul to you.

Comment: @TwilighT I don't remember the exact time. I'm sure it's under a second. The hu moments should be very fast since it is not a complex operation. The quadratic difference is very fast.